FiniteElement method cannot handle $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}=1$ well?
Consider this toy example:
$$\newcommand{\p}{\partial}\newcommand{\f}{\frac}
\left\{\begin{array}{l}\f{\p^2 u}{\p x \p y}=1\\
\left.u\right|_{x=0}=0\\
\left.u\right|_{y=0}=0\end{array}\right.$$
Obviously, the solution is $u=xy$, and the old good MethodOfLines can handle the problem well:
sys = With[{u = u[x, y]}, 
           {D[u, x, y] == 1, u == 0 /. x -> 0, u == 0 /. y -> 0}]

solref = NDSolveValue[sys, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];

Plot3D[solref[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]



Remark
"How do you know MethodOfLines is used in this case?" This is
discussed in the following post:
PDEs : automatic method choice : TensorProductGrid or FiniteElement?

But if we force NDSolve to use FiniteElement method, the result will be terrible:
solfem = NDSolveValue[sys, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Method -> "FiniteElement"];

Plot3D[solfem[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]


Why does FiniteElement method give a rather inaccurate (if we don't call it incorrect) solution? Is it a limitation of finite element method (FEM)? If so, can you elaborate? If not, how can we adjust FiniteElement method of NDSolve to make it produce an acceptable solution?
Please notice this question focuses on FEM, so solutions for the toy example via other methods are not of interest.

Nice question! How do you come to the conclusion "MethodOfLines is used"? Your link only checks for "FiniteElementMethod" I think.

@UlrichNeumann Because all the condition for triggering FEM isn't inside this NDSolve :) . And a critical evidence is, solref["ElementMesh"] returns None; another critical evidence is: https://i.sstatic.net/lEHjwX9F.png For comparison, the solution returned by FEM is: https://i.sstatic.net/nSb0NvhP.png

That is clear to me, but your implication "Not[FiniteElement] => MethodOfLines" isn't correct I think.

@UlrichNeumann This is correct, because currently (v14.1) MethodOfLines and FiniteElement are the only two methods available in NDSolve for PDE solving.

What about FDM TensorProductGrid?

@UlrichNeumann There's no method FDM. TensorProductGrid is amount to FDM, but it can only be a sub-method for SpatialDiscretization of MethodOfLines.

Have a look at tutorial/NDSolvePDE: " NDSolve uses finite element and finite difference methods for discretizing and solving PDEs. The numerical method of lines is used for time-dependent equations with either finite element or finite difference spatial discretizations, and details of this are described in the tutorial "The Numerical Method of Lines". "

@UlrichNeumann Perhaps not a mathematical proof: solmol =   NDSolveValue[sys, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Method -> "MethodOfLines"]; solmol === solref evaluates to True. It's unlikely distinct numerical methods produce identical solutions. In any case, an explicit MOL produces the same result.

@UlrichNeumann Well, I didn't know there exist such vague and misleading words in tutorial/NDSolvePDE, but its meaning is actually the same as what I mentioned in my last comment. "NDSolve uses finite element and finite difference methods for discretizing and solving PDEs" actually means "There exist 2 methods for spatial diccretization, FiniteElement and TensorProduct"

@MichaelE2 Thanks a lot , I like your  pseudo proof!

The problem is that there are no boundary conditions at $x=1, y=1$. As we know, in this case Mathematica FEM has an automatic option to apply zero Neumann value. Since these boundary conditions are not consistent with solution we have unstably result shown above. To avoid these discrepancies, we can apply Dirichlet conditions at $x=1, y=1$ as follows (we use low-level FEM-programming)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0., 0.}, {1, 0.}, {1, 1}, {0., 1}, {0.5, 0.5}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        1}}]}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01]
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", 
     "Space"} -> {{u}, {x, y}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {mesh}];
cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, 
   "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{{{0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0}}}}, 
   "LoadCoefficients" -> {{1}}];
bcdata = 
  InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, 
   sd, {{DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 0], 
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 0], 
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == y, x == 1], 
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == x, y == 1]}}];
mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
dpde = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata, sd];
dbc = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[bcdata, mdata, sd];
{load, stiffness, damping, mass} = dpde["All"];
DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, stiffness}, dbc];

v = LinearSolve[stiffness, load, 
    Method -> "Pardiso"][[1 ;; Length[mass]]];

solfun = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, v];

Plot3D[solfun[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"]



Interesting. Further tests show that this behavior seems to be related to the Div term in formal PDE of FEM: NDSolveValue[{u'[x] == 1, u[0] == 0}, u, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "FiniteElement"] gives the desired solution, but NDSolve[{-1 + Inactive[Div][{1} u[x], {x}] == 0, u[0] == 0}, u, {x, 0, 1}] doesn't. (In former case, the u'[x] has been transformed to part of the convection (Inactive[Grad][…]) term. )

@AlexTrounev Interesting workaround. I also tried to avoid this automatism "zero Neumann value" in my answer, but result isn't smooth. No idea why.

It's also interesting that, low-level FEM seems to be necessary and something like NDSolveValue[{sys[[1]], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == x y, True]}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] won't result in the desired solution. (Parser defect?)

@xzczd The main idea of my solution is not to give NDSolve any possibilities to apply automatic option to the x=1, y=1.   As we can see from all observed examples this option hidden very deep in the Mathematica FEM :)

@UlrichNeumann In your example you are not using InitializeBoundaryConditions, DiscretizeBoundaryConditions, and DeployBoundaryConditions to avoid automatic option with zero NeumannValue ; ) Obviously this option is hidden in DiscretizePDE.

@AlexTrounev Yes, that was my intention, discretize pde without any boundary conditions.

@UlrichNeumann But you can't discretize pde without any boundary conditions, since DiscretizePDE has automatic option to add zero NemannValue :)

@AlexTrounev Really? I have to check my answer for NeumannValue==0

@UlrichNeumann You should check stiffness matrix, and not solution.

@AlexTrounev Got it, thanks for your hint. That means for the case "No NeumannValue" we have to add the lineintegration (Green's identity) manually? Have to try it.

@AlexTrounev See my final addendum

final modification
Strange!
If we use Mathematicas FEM capabilities step by step, introducing DirichletConditions at the end, we get better results:
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

mesh
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[],"MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement","MeshOrder" -> 1]
mreg = MeshRegion[mesh];
pts = MeshCoordinates[mreg];

boundary DirichletCondition
rand = MeshCells[MeshRegion[mesh], {0, "Boundary"}][[All, 1]];
randD = Select[rand, (pts[[# ]][[1]] == 0 || pts[[# ]][[2]] == 0 &)]
rand1 = MeshCells[MeshRegion[mesh], {1, "Boundary"}][[All, 1]];

discretization(Mathematica buildin)
nr = ToNumericalRegion[mesh];
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables" -> {u},"Space" -> {x, y}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space" -> nr}];

coefficients = {"DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{-{{0, -1/2}, { -1/2,0}}}}, "LoadCoefficients" -> {{1}}}; 
initCoeffs =InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, coefficients];
methodData = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
discretePDE = DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, methodData, sd];
M11 = discretePDE["StiffnessMatrix"] // Normal;
rS = Flatten[discretePDE["LoadVector"] // Normal, 1];

solution M11.p-rS==0 && dirichlet==0
p = Table[u[i], {i, Length[pts]}]; (* unkowns*)
dirichlet = Table[p[[i]] == 0, {i, randD}]; (* DirchletCondition*)

mini = NMinimize[{# . # &[M11 . p - rS], dirichlet}, p]; 
Plot3D[Evaluate@ElementMeshInterpolation[mesh, Values[mini[[2]]]][x, y],Element[{x, y}, mreg]] 


Result approximates expected function u[x,y]==x y much better than "terrible" NDSolve result.
final addendum
Thanks @AlexTrounev for his helpful comment
discretePDE["StiffnessMatrix"] only evaluates the first part of Green's identity, assuming second part(line integral) equal zero(NeumannValue==0)
To get the correct discretization we have to add second part of Green's identity 
I don't know if discretePDE provides this integral somewhere, that's why I choose a selfmade numerical  approach
line integration(Gaussian)
linienintegralGaussNeumann[rand_, funx_, funy_, 
  pi_] := (*rand besteht aus Indexpaaren des Randes *)
 Block[{w0 = 8/18, w1 = 5/18, gt = 1/2, 
   gdt = Sqrt[3/5]/2,(*Gausspunkte tt-dtt,tt,tt+dtt*)
   x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, p1, p2, nx, ny},
  Total@Map[( 
       {p1, p2} = pi[[# ]];(*Punkte Randelement*)
       {nx, ny} = #/Sqrt[# . #] &[Cross[p2 - p1]];(* 
       Normalenvektor *)
       
        (* 3Gausspunkte*)
       {x0, y0} = (1 - gt) p1 + gt p2;
       {x1, y1} = (1 - (gt - gdt )) p1 + (gt - gdt ) p2;
       {x2, y2} = (1 - (gt + gdt)) p1 + (gt + gdt) p2;
       1/2 Norm[p2 - p1](* 
        Sehnenlänge*)(nx (funx[x1, y1] w1 + funx[x0, y0] w0 + 
             funx[x2, y2] w1) + 
          ny (funy[x1, y1] w1 + funy[x0, y0] w0 + 
             funy[x2, y2] w1) )) &, rand ](*//Rationalize[#,0]&*)/. 
   0. -> 0
  ]

boundary
\[Phi]i =Map[ElementMeshInterpolation[mesh, #] &,IdentityMatrix[Length[pts]]] ;   
\[Phi] = Map[ # [x, y] &, \[Phi]i] ;
\[Phi]x = Map[Derivative[1, 0][#][x, y] &, \[Phi]i] ;
\[Phi]y = Map[Derivative[0, 1][#][x, y] &, \[Phi]i] ;


intGreen = 
linienintegralGaussNeumann[rand1 , 
Function[{x, y}, Outer[Times, \[Phi] , \[Phi]y] // Evaluate], 
Function[{x, y}, Outer[Times, \[Phi] , \[Phi]x] // Evaluate], pts];

p = Table[u[i], {i, Length[pts]}];
dirichlet = Table[p[[i]] == 0, {i, randD}];
mini = NMinimize[{# . # &[ ((M11 - intGreen) . p - rS) ],dirichlet},
p]; 
Plot3D[Evaluate@ElementMeshInterpolation[mesh, Values[mini[[2]]]][x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh]]

Plot shows correct result of modified FEM (Galerkin method)!

Hope it helps!

Ah this is relatively easy to explain. Yours is different from the default FEM because: 1. The mesh is different. 2. NMinimize rather than LinearSolve is used to solve the system. If we: 1. Use the same mesh in NDSolve. 2. Use e.g. rSnew = Module[{r = rS}, r[[randD]]=0.; r];M11new=Module[{m = M11,c=ConstantArray[0., Length@rS]}, (m[[#]] = ReplacePart[c,#->1]) &/@randD; m]; mini2 = LinearSolve[M11new, rSnew]; Plot3D[Evaluate@ElementMeshInterpolation[mesh, mini2][x, y],{x, y}∈mreg] the solution will be almost the same. Also, this solution is just smoother, but still far beyond correct…

Forget to mention: "DiffusionCoefficients" should be {{{{0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0}}}}.

Last modification concerning discretePDE is absolutely right (+1}. The question is how discretePDE working with method of lines? Inside discretePDE we see branches dependent on method.

@AlexTrounev How did you look inside DiscretizePDE?

@UlrichNeumann Use GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@DiscretizePDE

@AlexTrounev Thanks, unfortunately my Mathematica (version 12.2) only opens an empty notebook. Do you think it is possible that the command DiscretizePDE also includes one-dimensional integrations of the elementfunctions?

@UlrichNeumann I think this good question could be addressed to user21 :)

Interesting. 1. Just a suggestion: you may consider omitting the exploring that's not strongly related to the final addendum section, usually short and sweet answer is better received :) . 2. Seems that you've forgotten to post some of the definitions e.g. rand1?

@xzczd My first addendum is a reply to your comments "easy to explain". Missing rand1 will be added, thanks

@xzczd I omitted the first addendum, thanks for your suggestion

@user21 Would you please have a look on this interesting question? Thanks.

Seems that \[Phi] and \[Phi]y are also missing? As to user21, I believe he has seen the question but he mentioned he's busy at the moment here. BTW, @ won't work if the user doesn't appear in the comment, you may want to read this.

Sorry, I added the definitions

This time \[Phi]i is missing 囧.

ups, I added definition and checked the code, runs in a frech kernel.
